# Use time as conditional to run a node in watson assistant IBM

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am using watson assistant from IBM.

I need the node's conational to be the current time, for example, if it is between 10:00 am and 2:00 pm, node A should run and if it is 3:00 p.m. at 8:00 p.m., the node B, has anyone done something similar? please help.

Comment: I have used the time functions in the expression language. Anything particular? There is also the "now" function: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-dates-now

Comment: Thank you very much, I took the documentation you sent me and everything worked perfectly. Thank you.